# Alternativa a lapply anidados

Tags: r

*Abro la pregunta para tener una referencia de las opciones disponibles, en español.*

Supongamos que tenemos un conjunto de datos como el siguiente:

```
set.seed(2018)
mi_df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F,
                    var1 = rnorm(50),
                    "grupo1" = sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 50, TRUE),
                    "grupo2" = sample(c("x", "y", "z"), 50, TRUE))
```

El objetivo es obtener la media de *var1* usando `mean`, para cada una de las combinaciones de *grupo1* y *grupo2* (ax, bx, cx, ay, by, etc.).

Una forma es anidando `lapply`, de modo que apliquemos la función `mean` para cada combinación. El primer `lapply` pasará por los valores de *grupo1* y el segundo, anidado, por los de *grupo2*

```
lapply(unique(mi_df[["grupo1"]]), function(x) {
  lapply(unique(mi_df[["grupo2"]]), function(y) {
    subconjunto <- subset(mi_df, grupo1 == x & grupo2 == y)
    mean(subconjunto[["var1"]])
  })
})
```

El resultado es una lista con nueve resultados (en realidad, una lista de tres listas, con tres resultados dentro de cada una).

Lo anterior puede volverse confuso con problemas más complejos.

¿Cómo podría obtener los mismos nueve resultados, pero sin anidar `lapply`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una alternativa usando tidyverse.

```r
set.seed(2018)
mi_df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F, var1 = rnorm(50), grupo1 = sample(c("a", 
  "b", "c"), 50, TRUE), grupo2 = sample(c("x", "y", "z"), 50, TRUE))



library(tidyverse)

mi_df %>% group_by(grupo1, grupo2) %>% summarise(var1 = mean(var1))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#> # Groups:   grupo1 [?]
#>   grupo1 grupo2     var1
#>   <chr>  <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1 a      x      -0.191  
#> 2 a      y      -0.00194
#> 3 a      z      -0.0456 
#> 4 b      x       0.739  
#> 5 b      y      -0.598  
#> 6 b      z      -0.404  
#> 7 c      x       0.154  
#> 8 c      y       1.51   
#> 9 c      z      -0.00164
```

Por que tidyverse? Imagina tienes mas variables, y mas variables por las cuales agrupar, y no solamente quieres la media, sino también varianza (y otras mas). Lo puedes hacer haciendo

```r
library(tidyverse)
data(mtcars)
mtcars2 <- select(mtcars, cyl, vs, am, mpg, hp, wt)
head(mtcars2)
#>                   cyl vs am  mpg  hp    wt
#> Mazda RX4           6  0  1 21.0 110 2.620
#> Mazda RX4 Wag       6  0  1 21.0 110 2.875
#> Datsun 710          4  1  1 22.8  93 2.320
#> Hornet 4 Drive      6  1  0 21.4 110 3.215
#> Hornet Sportabout   8  0  0 18.7 175 3.440
#> Valiant             6  1  0 18.1 105 3.460

mtcars2 %>%
  group_by(cyl, vs, am) %>%
  summarise_all(.funs = list(media = mean, varianza = var, minimo = min))
#> # A tibble: 7 x 12
#> # Groups:   cyl, vs [?]
#>     cyl    vs    am mpg_media hp_media wt_media mpg_varianza hp_varianza
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1  4.00  0     1.00      26.0     91.0     2.14       NA            NA  
#> 2  4.00  1.00  0         22.9     84.7     2.94        2.11        386  
#> 3  4.00  1.00  1.00      28.4     80.6     2.03       22.6         583  
#> 4  6.00  0     1.00      20.6    132       2.76        0.563      1408  
#> 5  6.00  1.00  0         19.1    115       3.39        2.66         84.2
#> 6  8.00  0     0         15.0    194       4.10        7.70       1113  
#> 7  8.00  0     1.00      15.4    300       3.37        0.320      2520  
#> # ... with 4 more variables: wt_varianza <dbl>, mpg_minimo <dbl>,
#> #   hp_minimo <dbl>, wt_minimo <dbl>
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que la forma más sencilla es "agrupando" mediante [`aggregate`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/aggregate.html) de la siguiente forma:

```
aggregate( var1 ~ grupo1 + grupo2 , mi_df, mean)
```

Lo que se hace es agrupar por `grupo1`y `grupo2` y aplicar `mean()` sobre los filas de cada uno de ellos. La salida:

```
  grupo1 grupo2         var1
1      a      x -0.191475371
2      b      x  0.738641761
3      c      x  0.154478780
4      a      y -0.001940531
5      b      y -0.598257655
6      c      y  1.507863033
7      a      z -0.045557242
8      b      z -0.404402472
9      c      z -0.001638198
```